# Update Core Data from a UISwitch inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiswitch

I have a static table that is bound to some `Core Data` values, I'm not sure how I would use `NSFetchedResultsController` in this instance, though I have seen discussions about how much more recommended it is.

I grab my `Core Data` object which is passed via `Segue`.

I also have a model that is setup to contain questions, with one of the properties containing the `Core Data` value (this is why I don't think I can use `NSFetchedResultsController`, as even though my Core Data entity contains some of the values I need, I'm not sure I would need a full data set)

```
self.surveyQuestion.append(SurveyQuestion(question: "Does the customer have a 'Proof of ownership'?", answer: coreDataEntity.isProofOfOwnership as Bool))
```

The questions are Survey related such as "Is your property X?" with a `UiSwitch` which is mapped to a `Core Data` value:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Configure the cell...
    let cell : SurveyQuestionTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SurveyQuestionCell") as! SurveyQuestionTableViewCell

    cell.lblQuestion.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    let surveyQuestion = self.surveyQuestion[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblQuestion.text = surveyQuestion.question
    cell.toggQuestion.on = surveyQuestion.answer
    if cell.toggQuestion.on {
                   cell.lblQuestion.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.accessoryType = .DetailDisclosureButton
    }

    return cell
}
```

Now, when I tap on the UISwitch I need it to update the Core Data value, and reload the table, its hooked up to a CustomTableViewCell like so:

***edit - Nearly got this thing working! heres my `UITableViewCell` class**

```
 class SurveyQuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    @IBOutlet weak var lblQuestion: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var toggQuestion: UISwitch!
    var surveyQuestionReference : SurveyQuestion?
    var tableViewReference : UITableView?

    @IBAction func toggledQuestion(sender: AnyObject) {
        let tempContext: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        tempContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext

        tempContext.performBlock({
            let entityName = "CoreDataEntity"
            let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", self.surveyQuestionReference!.id)
            do {

                let results = try tempContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [NSManagedObject]

                if results!.count > 0{

                        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext{
                            moc.performBlockAndWait({



                                for result in results!{
                                   result.setValue(self.toggQuestion.on, forKey: (self.surveyQuestionReference?.property)!)
                                }



                            })





                    }
                }
                do {
                    try tempContext.save()

                    //completion(finished: true)
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }

        })
        print(sender)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          self.tableViewReference!.reloadData()

        }

        }
```

I can obviously access the bit where the toggle is triggered, but this class doesn't know anything about the Core Data bit, I was thinking about using notifications but that just seems kind of messy...

Comment: are you saying that when you toggle a switch on one row of the table, you want to reload the whole table?  what do you change?

Comment: The UISwitch is bound to a Core Data value, when that changes it needs to update the Core Data entity and also reload the table as there is some additional logic around those Boolean values, e.g when one switch is changed on the table, the other rows need to disappear

Comment: ok - I understand that you can, in theory just get the parent of a cell through self.superview, but you might be better storing a reference to the tableview as part of the custom cell class as well!
I have updated my answer again, just to keep it all in one place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create your cell, pass in a reference to the coredata object, and the tableView itself and store them as attributes of SurveyQuestionTableViewCell, then you can do everything you need to in setSelected()

in your custom cell class, add an attribute for the question

```
class SurveyQuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblQuestion: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var toggQuestion: UISwitch!

    var surveyQuestionReference : SurveyQuestionType
    vat tableViewReference : UITableView
    ...
```

and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath after you create the cell

```
cell.surveyQuestionReference = surveyQuestion
cell.tableViewReference = tableView
```

where SurveyQuestionType is whatever you have previously defined

in setSelected, you can use those stored attributes

```
surveyQuestionReference = self.toggQuestion.on
tableViewReference.reloadData()
```

Comment: do you have an example of how to pass the reference?

Comment: sorry im not understanding, whereabouts in my cell definition? Do you mean the class ie. SurveyQuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell or inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath function?

Comment: Thanks, I can access the model, though I still dont know how to update the Core Data model...or reload the table?

Comment: ahh i get it, am i alright performing the Core Data stuff in this CustomTableViewCell class aswell, or is there a better method of updating the entity?

Comment: no - store a reference to the tableView in each of your custom cell types.

Comment: I'm a big fan of singletons as a way of sharing access to the data model like this.  If you do that, and put a reference to the CoreData stuff, the tableView, and even the data that you've loaded from the database, you can use a single shared instance to access everything you need - in the cell, in the tableview, in the view containing the table, and in other views.

Comment: are there any examples of this? I'm currently using the app delegate as a way of getting everyone access to the moc

Comment: its more or less all working, except when I trigger the UISwitch it just kind of stutters and doesn't change value until i exit the view and return, i expect its to do with reloadData() but I'm not sure where else to put it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, using a shared Instance

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreData


class DataModelInstance : NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var appDelegate         : AppDelegate?
    var managedContext      : NSManagedObjectContext?
    var persistentStoreCoordinator         : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?

    // plus whatever else you need

class var sharedInstance : DataModelInstance
{
    struct Singleton
    {
        static let instance = DataModelInstance()
    }


    return Singleton.instance
}
```

and then in any class which needs access to this data model

```
var dataModel = DataModelInstance.sharedInstance
```

I know there are those who just won't ever use singletons, but it can be a much more elegant solution to making these attributes available where they are needed

With a shared data model, you can simply move all of your data attributes out of the class they are currently in, and reference them through the data model - then if you have the same data model in your custom cell class, you can do whatever you can do in the main view.  To keep your GUI and processing logic separate, you can put everything in the data model

```
dataModel.refreshTable()
```

and then define a function in the data model that takes care of your table view - you could save all current edits to the data, and reload, without having to put any of that logic in individual cell classes

Comment: Seems like a far cleaner approach, though i'm a bit too far down the rabbit hole with this project at the minute, Are there any tutorial projects that use this approach? Just so I can see how a project would be put together in its entirety?

Comment: looks like you'\re probably right.  I couldn't find any single tutorial that covers both the singleton and database side of this, but there are plenty of tutorials out there on how to implement singletons, and I think the latest version of swift may have simplified it even more http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80246/swift-1-2-singleton-implementation

Answer (score 0):

for updating any record in core data try to use this code:

```
let managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext=(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
let req=NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity Name")
req.returnsObjectsAsFaults=false
let result:NSArray=try! managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(req)

if result.count>0{

let res=result[Int(indexPath.row!]as! NSManagedObject
res.setValue("The Value", forKey: "Key Name")
 do {
     try managedObjectContext.save()
     } catch _ { print("Update Unsuccessful") }
```

Comment: but shouldnt SurveyQuestionTabelViewCell not know anything about the Core Data object, i thought this kind of thing was bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `[unowned self] in` within the closure. See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). This is how it's done. See also [CoreDataKit](https://github.com/mac-cain13/CoreDataKit/blob/master/CoreDataKit/NSManagedObjectContext.swift), a 28-star github repo Core Data stack. It's available on cocoapods and honestly, why not just drop something like this into your app and not worry about "unowned selves" and other philosophical brain twisters, eh?

```
if let moc = self.managedObjectContext{
                        moc.performBlockAndWait({

                            /* In here we are in a closure (Swift version of a block), so "self" is problematic. Use unowned self instead (in objective c you'd have to do weak self). */
                            [unowned self] in
                            for result in results!{
                               result.setValue(self.toggQuestion.on, 
                                      forKey: (self.surveyQuestionReference?.property)!)
                            }


                        })
                    }
```